# Regex String for Restructuring Author Firstname, Lastname, Title

Tags: regex

I want to convert strings in the format

```
The European Union - A Very Short Introduction - Pinder, John
```

to

```
John Pinder - The European Union - A Very Short Introduction
```

I am having trouble matching on "Pinder" and "John" to reformat in the desired way.

Comment: What do you expect are the permutations to this ? For instance, what if the title doesn't contain a dash and the name is not in the form of _last,first_ ? Example: `European Union Short Introduction - John Pinder` I'd say this is not answerable via your current example. Otherwise, its this `^[^\S\r\n]*(.*?)[^\S\r\n]*-[^\S\r\n]*(?:([^-,\r\n]]+?)?,)?[^\S\r\n]*([^-\r\n]+?)?[^\S\r\n]*$`

Comment: Good point - few permutations are expected in my case, although I understand that some data sets could include multiple authors, punctuated author names, book titles with commas, etc.  I am not using a programmatic regex framework but am actually plugging match and replace strings into an existing tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(.*?)(?:-\s+(\w+),\s+(\w+))$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eU2yL6/3)

If you may have authors with multiple names (such as 'von Clausewitz, Carl') this won't work. Instead, maybe:

```
^(.*)(?:-\s+([^,]+?),\s+(\w+))$
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/eU2yL6/4)

Comment: Very helpful - thank you!  It works great, and I learned about regex101.com . . . !

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to approach the problem, all requiring some assumptions not specified in your question. Here is one solution...

```
^.+-\s+(.+),\s+(.+)$
```

[regexper diagram](http://regexper.com/#%5E.%2B-%5Cs%2B(.%2B)%2C%5Cs%2B(.%2B)%24)
[image]

It is working by consuming as many characters as possible (up to first capture group, using hyphen and whitespace as delimiter) then it assumes there is a comma followed by whitespace separating first name from last name, which it assumes is the end of the string.

Depending on what you know about the uniformity of the data, this may or may not work for you, but I thought it would be nice to have a solution which does not try to restrict characters in name, but rather the rest of the format.

Comment: Very helpful - thanks!  I had not seen that regex visualizer before.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
  $code = preg_match_all('/(?:.*?) - (?:.*?) -(.*?),(.*)/', $string,$matches);
```

This will give you an array and `$matches[1]` will give you the last name (in this case "Pinder") and `$matches[2]` will give you the first name ("John"). You can then turn it back into a string if you want to using `$lastname = implode('',$matches[1]);`.